# pandas check if value exists in one specific index in a MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a `MultiIndex` data frame called `df` with 3 `indexes` (Fruit, Color, Taste). I want to search 1 specific `index`, that `index` being  `Color`  and see if the `value` exists in it.

For example: the code would look something like this. `Color` is an `index` in the dataframe not just a column.

```
if 'purple' in 'Color':
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

I only want it to search the `Color` not any other `indexes/columns`

```
                       Quantity     Quality
Fruit   Color   Taste
apple   red     tart     12          good
lemon   yellow  sour     11          average
grapes  purple  sweet     5          bad
lime    green   citrus    3          excellent
```

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get_level_values` to filter.

```
if "purple" in df.index.get_level_values('Color'):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this if you want a tabular output:

```
def check(data:pd.DataFrame,l:list):
    c = data.index.get_level_values("Color").isin(l)
    return np.where(c,'yes','no')

df['Result'] = check(df,['purple'])
```

---

```
print(df)

                       Quantity    Quality Result
Fruit  Color  Type                              
apple  red    tart          12       good     no
lemon  yellow sour          11    average     no
grapes purple sweet          5        bad    yes
lime   green  citrus         3  excellent     no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the value is in `index.unique(level)`. This way the whole index would not need to be copied into a list. It might also make the subsequent search faster.

```
if "purple" in df.index.unique(level="Color"): 
    print("yes")
else: 
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that df.index.get_level_values('level_name') is the right approach. However, I think the more standard pandas implementation would be to use a vectorised approach returning a boolean series (granted this wasn't exactly what the OP asked for):

```
is_purple = df.index.get_level_values('color') == 'purple' # <-- result is a boolean series
# Then filter as needed
only_purple = df[is_purple]
# Or use np.where to get yes/no strings if needed
df['Result'] = np.where(is_purple, 'yes', 'no')
```